# React input.focus() called by `ref` also invoking `onBlur` event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an input element in React that I want to set `onFocus`, `onBlur`, and `ref` callbacks for. Setting the `ref` callback is having the unwanted behavior of firing the `onBlur` event when I run `input.focus()` inside of it.

```
<input
    onFocus={() => {
        props.startSearch(); // set props.active === true
    }}
    onBlur={() => {
        props.endSearch(); // set props.active === false
    }}
    ref={(input) => {
        if (input && props.active) {
            input.focus();
        }
    }}
/>
```

I have another component that dispatches an action setting `props.active` to true. This should focus the input component. However, when the component mounts, the input's `onBlur` callback fires unexpectedly:

`ref => onFocus => onBlur`

This is setting `props.active` to true, but then immediately setting it false (because `props.endSearch` fires).

When I comment out `input.focus()` and manually click to focus the input, I get `onFocus => ref`, which is the desired behavior. This clearly does not have the effect of "auto-focusing" the input, however.

---

*Why is `input.focus()` triggering `onBlur` to fire and how can I prevent this?*

Comment: You mean the desired behavior is `ref => onFocus`, right? My only guess is that something else is stealing focus shortly after you assign focus on the input. Where does focus end up?

Comment: Yes, `ref => onFocus` is the desired behavior. The active element is just `body`, not sure how it could be stealing focus...

Comment: What does `document.querySelector(":focus")` give you?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `autoFocus`. Like:

```
<input ref="searchBox" onFocus={props.startSearch} onBlur={props.endSearch} autoFocus={props.active} />
```

**Edit:**

Also, in your `componentDidUpdate` do (note the updated `ref` above):

```
if (this.props.active) {
  this.refs.searchBox.focus();
}
```

Comment: `autoFocus` (when `props.active` is set to true) seems to update when I refresh the page, but does not have the effect of reflecting the prop value... In other words, it doesn't update dynamically.

Comment: I'm trying to handle these stateful actions from a parent component, can I assign and access refs from parent components?

Comment: You can't assign and access refs from a parent component. My answer has nothing to do with React state. It's just your child component reacting to its props.

Comment: No such luck, onBlur is still firing after the updates in `componentDidUpdate`...

Comment: Have you tried putting `console.log(document.querySelector(":focus"))` right before you focus it in `componentDidUpdate`?

Comment: it returns `null`.